# Problem with indexing last_modified field for Open Documents

Tags: solr

I installed Solr 8.1 and when I try to index Open Documents (ods, odt, ...) an invalid date error for last_modified is thrown. With other document formats (pdf, doc, ...) the indexing works normally.

schema.xml definition for the field:

> `<field name="last_modified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
>   ...
>   <fieldType name="date" class="solr.DatePointField" docValues="true"/>`

Exception:

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR:
>   [doc=D42039220124097949-A100020965] Error adding field
>   'last_modified'='2019-06-14T16:59:47.610000000' msg=Invalid Date
>   String:'2019-06-14T16:59:47.610000000'    at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:215)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand.getLuceneDocument(AddUpdateCommand.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.updateDocOrDocValues(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:968)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.doNormalUpdate(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:289)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:236)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:257)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doVersionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:483)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.lambda$versionAdd$0(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:337)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.VersionBucket.runWithLock(VersionBucket.java:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:337)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:223)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingDocumentLoader.doAdd(ExtractingDocumentLoader.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingDocumentLoader.addDoc(ExtractingDocumentLoader.java:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingDocumentLoader.load(ExtractingDocumentLoader.java:237)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)
>     at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2566)    at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:756)
>     at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:542)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:397)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:343)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1588)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1557)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Invalid Date
>   String:'2019-06-14T16:59:47.610000000'    at
>   org.apache.solr.util.DateMathParser.parseMath(DateMathParser.java:247)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.util.DateMathParser.parseMath(DateMathParser.java:226)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.schema.DatePointField.createField(DatePointField.java:214)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.schema.PointField.createFields(PointField.java:250)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.addField(DocumentBuilder.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:171)
>     ... 58 more

Comment: Did you ever get the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it turned out that instead of passing Date object I should have passed the String representation of Date by calling toString(). In my case it was LocalDateTime -

```
Object value = ((LocalDateTime) value).toString();
solrDoc.addField("last_login_on", value);
```